# Why does Scanner nextLine() read one file but not another in the same directory?

Tags: java

I have two files in a directory. Both of them have lines of text in them. According to Notepad++, each line has a CRLF. My ReadFile class reads one file and not the other and not the other.

```
private FileRead fileRead = new FileRead();
private JobSiteData jobSiteData = new JobSiteData();
private String path = "C:/Users/Antonio/IdeaProjects/JobSearch/websiteTest/";
```

If I uncomment out the block and comment out the other block it works fine.

```
  @Test
    void setAllText_ItReturnsAllLinesFromSite_arrayListOfLinesFromSite() throws IOException {
    //        ArrayList<String> thisWorks = new ArrayList<>();
    //        thisWorks = fileRead.getLinesFromFile(path + "allTextTest.txt");
    //        for (String s : thisWorks) {
    //            System.out.println(s);
    //        }

        ArrayList<String> thisDoesntWork = new ArrayList<>();
        thisDoesntWork = fileRead.getLinesFromFile(path + "goDaddySplitTestAllLines.txt");
        for (String s : thisDoesntWork) {
            System.out.println(s); // prints "File is empty."
        }
    }
```

Here is my FileRead Class.

```
public class FileRead {

    private String fileName;
    private ArrayList<String> linesFromFile = new ArrayList<>();
    private Scanner fileScanner;

    public ArrayList<String> getLinesFromFile(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        setLinesFromFile();
        if (isFileEmpty()) {
            linesFromFile.add("File is empty.");
        }
        return linesFromFile;
    }

    private void setLinesFromFile() {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        if (doesFileExist(file)) {
            readFile();
            closeFileReader();
        }
    }

    private Boolean doesFileExist(File file) {
        try {
            fileScanner = new Scanner(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            linesFromFile.add("File does not exist.");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void readFile() {
        if (fileScanner != null) {
            if (!linesFromFile.isEmpty()) {
                linesFromFile.clear();
            }
            while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                linesFromFile.add(fileScanner.nextLine());
            }
        }
    }

    private void closeFileReader() {
        if (fileScanner != null) {
            fileScanner.close();
        }
    }

    private boolean isFileEmpty() {
        return linesFromFile.size() == 0;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I found the issue. For some reason this line in the file is causing the scanner not to read the lines.

"GoDaddy’s Productivity suite of products help millions of small businesses run and grow their ventures. We are looking for an engineer that is passionate about software development to help accelerate our growth. If you’re into building world-class experiences on public cloud infrastructure using JavaScript and React, learning new things, and working with a fun team, we want to meet you!"

This line is the forth line down. If I delete it and everything after it, the scanner works fine. If I delete everything in the file and only have that line in the file as the first line it won't work either. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not read the file"? - what bad behavior are you getting? - Oh...just noticed the comment in your code.  So you just get no lines in one case, right?

Comment: This is a job for your debugger.  Step through the code and see what is happening.  I expect you'll find the place in your code where the code is breaking out of the read loop thinking that there is no more data in the file. - you might also want to instead or in addition add some print statements that will help you see what's going on. - for example, maybe the code thinks the file doesn't exist. Running in the debugger or adding some print statements would tell you that.

Comment: @Steve Yes I get a "File is empty." I have stepped through the debugger. As the original post said. "nextline()" I mean that's where I end up. It doesn't read anything at all. Yet there is text in the file.

Comment: The more important line is `filescanner.hasNextLine()` because that's what is going to return 'false' and exit the loop.  That line must be returning `false` right away, or you'd be getting at least blank lines in `linesFromFile`, and you would not get the "file is empty" message, right? - I don't seen any problems in your code.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I don't see any problems either. I have other files in the exact same directory and it reads those just fine. It's just one specific file it won't read.

Comment: I'd say eliminate as many assumptions as possible.  For example, copy the text out of the file that isn't working and paste it into one of the ones that is.  This will separate the issue of the file's name/location from the contents of the file.  Depending on the results, that will at least tell you something and limit your search somewhat. - I've run into these sorts of "it has to work" situations many times.  It's usually something somewhat obvious once you figure it out.

Comment: @Steve I found the issue. I started to delete lines from the file. I removed all of them except one and it read it just fine. I found the line that is the issue. I am going to look into this line and see what's going on with it. I will report back

Comment: For some reason, this line is causing the scanner not to work. It's the forth line down. If I delete it, it reads the three lines above it. this is the line. "GoDaddy’s Productivity suite of products help millions of small businesses run and grow their ventures. We are looking for an engineer that is passionate about software development to help accelerate our growth. If you’re into building world-class experiences on public cloud infrastructure using JavaScript and React, learning new things, and working with a fun team, we want to meet you!"